# osx docker run elasticsearch for development

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm using docker to run elasticsearch in single-node for development.
It's running well on Ubuntu, but something is wrong on OSX.

Here is how I run ES.

```
docker run --rm --name es \
  -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 \
  -e "discovery.type=single-node" \
  -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" \
  docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.1
```

when I use curl to see if it works

```
curl 127.0.0.1:9200/_health?pretty
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "No endpoint or operation is available at [_health]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "No endpoint or operation is available at [_health]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

This only happens on OSX.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/cluster-health.html   Just `_cluster` is forgotten?  `127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty` ?

Comment: @Alex you are right.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex said, I miss a _cluter.

```
curl 127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
```